# When does this occur? and Why? Android App Activity being shutdown 2.3.3 emulator with error

Tags: android

```
08-16 17:37:37.694: ERROR/InputDispatcher(61): channel '40803d28 com.myApp.android/com.myApp.android.PickActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
08-16 17:37:37.694: ERROR/InputDispatcher(61): channel '40803d28 com.myApp.android/com.myApp.android.PickActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Sometimes I also see this message.

```
08-16 17:44:21.092: ERROR/InputDispatcher(61): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=177, events=0x8
```

So this only only happens in 2.3.3 emulator and not on 3.0 or 2.2 or any other emulators I have tested on and even works great on my Froyo Droid Incredible real device. No errors nothing.

Whenever I open the App's main Activity in 2.3.3 emulator, after a little bit like 5-7 secs invariably I see the log message above and the activity closes down. I am not sure what this means. I have never seen this before.

Here are some code snippets of the activity. This is the main activity of the App that is displayed to the user when logged in to the App and then they can choose from 4 icons that launches their respective activities.

Also I guess worth mentioning is that this Activity has a MillenialMedia Banner Ad bottom that once again fetched Ads and works fine in all other emulators and devices.

public class PickActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, MMAdListener{

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Instantiate shared preferences
        mAppPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        mEditor = mAppPreferences.edit();
        // Instantiate the views
        setupViews();
        Hashtable<String, String> map = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        map.put("keywords", "shopping,deals,money,coupons,sports");
        //include additional metadata or settings in the hashmap

        MMAdView adView = new MMAdView(this, MYAPID, MMAdView.BANNER_AD_BOTTOM, 30, map);
        adView.setId(123);
        FrameLayout adFrameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.mm_layout);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adFrameLayout.addView(adView, lp); 

}
```

Then I have implemented onStart, onStop and onResume.

Here is the setupViews method

```
private void setupViews() {

        yourA = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.MA);
        yourA.setOnClickListener(this);
        yourC = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.MC);
        yourC.setOnClickListener(this);
        yourM = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.MM);
        yourM.setOnClickListener(this);
        yourS = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.MS);
        yourS.setOnClickListener(this);
        //Action bar Help button
        helpButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ActionHelpButton);
        helpButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        // Action bar Video button
        videoButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ActionVideoButton);
        videoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        videoButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        // Footer marquee TextView
        footerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.FooterMarquee);         
    }
```

I have also added the MMAdListener default methods in the class with Log messages.

Please help me find out why this is happening only in 2.3.3 emulator and activity is shut down.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. My app is calling a REST service so adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

to the android manifest fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as it's a "spurious callback" message, I suspect it has something to do with the MMAdListener you have registered.

Try unregistering (commenting out) the listener and see if it continues to happen.

If it does, I would try repairing the AVD.  If that does not work, delete it and remake the AVD.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So I commented out the listener and also removed the ad view as a whole from the activity. It happens again. I really want to test this thing on a real android device running 2.3.3.

Comment: Sometimes you just have emulator limitations, unfortunately.  Did you try deleting and recreating the emulator?

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to mention that! Repair button for this 2.3.3 AVD is disabled in the AVD Manager but I deleted and recreated it. Still same issue.

Comment: I haven't tried 2.3.4 but have tried 3.0 and it works fine in 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Benni05 found a solution [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/102620-Unity-3.4-android-app-crashes-on-startup-UnityPlayer-has-no-id), by setting android:configChanges="orientation" property for activity @AndroidManifest. It work for me(where i get an error with api lvl.11 installed devices). Good luck!